# MacOS Calendar issue

Tags: ios, icloud, calendar, ical, google-calendar

My Calendar app is configured to read more than one calendar (iCloud, Google, Exchange). If I create an event from my computer, it won't be visible on all other calendars, and if I create an event on any of my iOS devices I cannot see on the Mac Desktop Calendar.

I tried to remove Calendar from iCloud Settings on my Mac but, I did not get any luck.

Answer (score 2):

First, check your iPhone:

For **iCloud Calendar**, check whether it is enabled on both devices under `Settings > Apple ID > iCloud`

For **Google**, check whether *Fetch New Data* is set to *Push* in `Settings > Passwords and Accounts` and also  under *Gmail* look, whether is it enabled or not.

For Exchange try the same.

Now check the same settings on your mac.